# Mac Mini to Apple TV

Tags: macos, appletv

I know how to move YouTube and other material from my iPhone into the Apple TV. But, as I've just purchased a Mac Mini, I'm wondering, how can I move material from the **Mac Mini** into the **Apple TV**?

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention which AppleTV you own, so I am going to assume that it's the currently available model, or at least *generation*, because it's probably more likely, and its easier to answer :)

The answer it that you cannot move stuff onto the AppleTV, it's a streaming only solution.  Whilst it has a small amount of internal storage (I think 4Gb for the 1st version of the 2nd Gen model that I have) this is used to buffer streaming, particularly for movie rentals from iTunes etc.

So to simply view, rather than move, content that is held on your Mac Mini, or any device come to that, is to ensure that it is playable in a player that offers the chance to use AirPlay to wirelessly stream the content.  You'll need to be on the same LAN as the AppleTV to see the device, but assuming you are you should simply see it as an output source when you click the AirPlay symbol in the player.

Answer (score 1):

Your Apple TV doesn't have any significant storage; it is a stream only device. Other than YouTube, you didn't mention what content you're trying to "move", which I think you mean "view". You want to view content on your Apple TV regardless of whether then are on your phone or on your mini.

You have three options, assuming that your three devices are on the same network:

1. **Airplay**. You can use Airplay from your phone and our mini to broadcast several types of content to your Apple TV.
2. **iTunes**. If you turn on your iTunes sharing (iTunes, preferences, Sharing) and tell tell your Apple TV to use that computer, you can stream any content you have on iTunes.
3. **Apple TV Apps**. There are a bunch of apps on your Apple TV, including YouTube and Netflix.

Enjoy!

Comment: Clearly I don't understand the editing policy on this site. Love the new formatting, but changing my text from "you are" to "you're" adds no value and changes the style of my prose. Also, I was being overly descriptive on the network type as it was clear that the person asking the question was a novice. Please reconsider making edits like this in the future. Unless you are correcting actual spelling mistakes, please leave my text as I wrote it. Thanks.

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/editing .. you can always edit your own post, too, if you don't like part of an edit somebody else made.